# SQLBindCol: SQL_VARBINARY column to SQL_C_WCHAR buffer: Does not get converted to string representation

Tags: c++, mysql, odbc, mysql-connector, data-conversion

I'm trying to read the value of a varbinary column directly into a string buffer. I'm wondering **who is responsible for converting the binary data into some string representation**? Like for a binary value of `0xAB` I would like to get the string `0xAB` instead of a single character with the decimal value `171`.

I thought that in ODBC it should be enough to tell the driver the buffertype of the buffer a column is bound to. The driver will then do all required conversion (if it is possible and implemented) or return an error in case of failure. The source for this assumption is the document [SQL to C: Binary](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/odbc/reference/appendixes/sql-to-c-binary), which says:

> When binary SQL data is converted to character C data, each byte (8
>   bits) of source data is represented as two ASCII characters. These
>   characters are the ASCII character representation of the number in its
>   hexadecimal form. For example, a binary 00000001 is converted to "01"
>   and a binary 11111111 is converted to "FF".

**Example**: Assume I have a varbinary column in my table. If I use `SQL_C_BINARY` as 3rd argument for `SQLBindCol`, the driver will return binary data into my `SQLCHAR` buffer. If I use `SQL_C_CHAR`, the driver will convert the binary values into a string-representation. The same if I use `SQL_C_WCHAR` and a `SQLWCHAR` buffer. This works at least for Sql Server, IBM DB2 and Access: The binary value of the column is `0xabcdef`. If I query that column and read the result into a `SQL_C_WCHAR`, the string held will display `ABCDEF`. If I read it into a `SQL_C_BINARY` buffer, only three bytes holding `171` (ab), `205` (cd) and `239` (ef) are filled.

Now I tried the same using `MySql ODBC 5.3 Unicode Driver`. There no conversion happens: If I bind a `SQL_C_CHAR` or `SQL_C_BINARY` buffer, three bytes are filled. Similar if I bind to a `SQL_C_WCHAR`: The first three `SQLWCHAR` elements are filled with the three values `171`, `205` and `239`.

It works as expected if in my query I explicit ask for hex values:

> SELECT HEX(varblob) FROM test

**So, finally the actual question:** Is this correct, intended behavior of MySql ODBC connector and I just need to explicitly do a `HEX()` or am I missing some settings in the ODBC Connector / Database? Also from the background that converting is done implicit for integer, datetime, etc. columns also with MySql, but not (in my case) for varbinary columns..

For completeness, here is a (unfortunately not so minimal) example demonstrating the problem.

It will create a table `test` with two columns: An id-column as integer and a varbinary column and one row is inserted into the table. The row holds the value `0xabcdef`. Then it tries to read the data from the varbinary column: First as binary to compare if the returned result is what we expect, then by binding to a `SQLWCHAR` buffer without explicitly doing `HEX()` and as last try with explicit converting to `HEX()`:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <sql.h>
#include <sqlext.h>
#include <sqlucode.h>

void printErr(SQLHANDLE handle, SQLSMALLINT handleType)
{
    SQLSMALLINT recNr = 1;
    SQLRETURN ret = SQL_SUCCESS;
    while (ret == SQL_SUCCESS || ret == SQL_SUCCESS_WITH_INFO)
    {
        SQLWCHAR errMsg[SQL_MAX_MESSAGE_LENGTH + 1];
        SQLWCHAR sqlState[5 + 1];
        errMsg[0] = 0;
        SQLINTEGER nativeError;
        SQLSMALLINT cb = 0;
        ret = SQLGetDiagRec(handleType, handle, recNr, sqlState, &nativeError, errMsg, SQL_MAX_MESSAGE_LENGTH + 1, &cb);
        if (ret == SQL_SUCCESS || ret == SQL_SUCCESS_WITH_INFO)
        {
            std::wcerr << L"ERROR; native: " << nativeError << L"; state: " << sqlState << L"; msg: " << errMsg << std::endl;
        }
        ++recNr;
    }
}


int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    // connect to db
    SQLRETURN   nResult = 0;
    SQLHANDLE   handleEnv = 0;

    nResult = SQLAllocHandle(SQL_HANDLE_ENV, SQL_NULL_HANDLE, (SQLHANDLE*)&handleEnv);
    nResult = SQLSetEnvAttr(handleEnv, SQL_ATTR_ODBC_VERSION, (SQLPOINTER)SQL_OV_ODBC3_80, SQL_IS_INTEGER);

    SQLHANDLE   handleDBC = 0;
    nResult = SQLAllocHandle(SQL_HANDLE_DBC, handleEnv, (SQLHANDLE*)&handleDBC);

    SQLWCHAR     strConnect[256] = L"Provider=MSDASQL;Driver={MySQL ODBC 5.3 UNICODE Driver};Server=192.168.0.222;Database=test;User=foo;Password=bar;Option=3;";
    SQLWCHAR     strConnectOut[1024] = { 0 };
    SQLSMALLINT nNumOut = 0;
    nResult = SQLDriverConnect(handleDBC, NULL, (SQLWCHAR*)strConnect, SQL_NTS, (SQLWCHAR*)strConnectOut, sizeof(strConnectOut), &nNumOut, SQL_DRIVER_NOPROMPT);
    if (!SQL_SUCCEEDED(nResult))
        printErr(handleDBC, SQL_HANDLE_DBC);

    // Allocate a statement
    SQLHSTMT    handleStatement = SQL_NULL_HSTMT;
    nResult = SQLAllocHandle(SQL_HANDLE_STMT, handleDBC, (SQLHANDLE*)&handleStatement);
    if (!SQL_SUCCEEDED(nResult))
        printErr(handleDBC, SQL_HANDLE_DBC);

    // Define what we expect to read back:
    const SQLCHAR EXPECTED_VAL[3] = { 0xab, 0xcd, 0xef };

    // Create a table and insert a value
    // dont care if dropping fails
    nResult = SQLExecDirect(handleStatement, L"DROP TABLE test", SQL_NTS);
    nResult = SQLExecDirect(handleStatement, L"CREATE TABLE `test` ( `idtest` int(11) NOT NULL, `varblob` varbinary(10) DEFAULT NULL)", SQL_NTS);
    if (!SQL_SUCCEEDED(nResult))
        printErr(handleStatement, SQL_HANDLE_STMT);
    nResult = SQLExecDirect(handleStatement, L"INSERT INTO test (idtest, varblob) VALUES(1, 0xabcdef)", SQL_NTS);
    if (!SQL_SUCCEEDED(nResult))
        printErr(handleStatement, SQL_HANDLE_STMT);
    SQLFreeStmt(handleStatement, SQL_CLOSE);

    // Prepare some columns to read the results: Read as SQL_C_BINARY:
    SQLLEN cbId, cbBlob;
    SQLWCHAR idCol[20];
    SQLCHAR binBlobCol[100];
    memset(idCol, 0, sizeof(idCol));
    memset(binBlobCol, 0, sizeof(binBlobCol));

    // Let the driver convert id-col to wchar..
    nResult = SQLBindCol(handleStatement, 1, SQL_C_WCHAR, idCol, sizeof(idCol), &cbId);
    if (!SQL_SUCCEEDED(nResult))
        printErr(handleStatement, SQL_HANDLE_STMT);

    // Bind varbinary column to binary buffer
    nResult = SQLBindCol(handleStatement, 2, SQL_C_BINARY, binBlobCol, sizeof(binBlobCol), &cbBlob);
    if (!SQL_SUCCEEDED(nResult))
        printErr(handleStatement, SQL_HANDLE_STMT);

    // Do some query
    nResult = SQLExecDirect(handleStatement, L"SELECT idtest, varblob FROM test WHERE idtest = 1", SQL_NTS);
    if (!SQL_SUCCEEDED(nResult))
        printErr(handleStatement, SQL_HANDLE_STMT);

    nResult = SQLFetch(handleStatement);
    if (!SQL_SUCCEEDED(nResult))
        printErr(handleStatement, SQL_HANDLE_STMT);

    // memory-compare, to test if value read is equal to what we expect:
    bool isEqual = (memcmp(EXPECTED_VAL, binBlobCol, 3) == 0);
    std::wcout << L"Values are equal: " << isEqual << std::endl;
    std::wcout << L"Length of data read is " << cbBlob << std::endl;

    SQLFreeStmt(handleStatement, SQL_UNBIND);
    SQLFreeStmt(handleStatement, SQL_CLOSE);

    // Now try to let the driver convert the binary values into some human-friendly WCHAR data:
    SQLWCHAR wcharBlobCol[100];
    memset(idCol, 0, sizeof(idCol));
    memset(wcharBlobCol, 0, sizeof(wcharBlobCol));

    nResult = SQLBindCol(handleStatement, 1, SQL_C_WCHAR, idCol, sizeof(idCol), &cbId);
    if (!SQL_SUCCEEDED(nResult))
        printErr(handleStatement, SQL_HANDLE_STMT);

    nResult = SQLBindCol(handleStatement, 2, SQL_C_WCHAR, wcharBlobCol, sizeof(wcharBlobCol), &cbBlob);
    if (!SQL_SUCCEEDED(nResult))
        printErr(handleStatement, SQL_HANDLE_STMT);

    // Do some query
    nResult = SQLExecDirect(handleStatement, L"SELECT idtest, varblob FROM test WHERE idtest = 1", SQL_NTS);
    if (!SQL_SUCCEEDED(nResult))
        printErr(handleStatement, SQL_HANDLE_STMT);

    nResult = SQLFetch(handleStatement);
    if (!SQL_SUCCEEDED(nResult))
        printErr(handleStatement, SQL_HANDLE_STMT);

    // print results: Doesnt look like the driver did convert anything.. 
    std::wcout << L"Id: " << idCol << std::endl;
    std::wcout << L"Blob: " << wcharBlobCol << std::endl;

    // Driver just copies binary data into wchar buffer
    std::wcout << L"0: " << (int)wcharBlobCol[0] << L" 1: " << (int)wcharBlobCol[1] << L" 2: " << (int)wcharBlobCol[2] << std::endl;

    // If we ask the driver to convert explicitely, it gets converted:
    // But do we really need to do that (compared to db2, sql server, access...) ???
    SQLFreeStmt(handleStatement, SQL_CLOSE);
    nResult = SQLExecDirect(handleStatement, L"SELECT idtest, HEX(varblob) FROM test WHERE idtest = 1", SQL_NTS);
    if (!SQL_SUCCEEDED(nResult))
        printErr(handleStatement, SQL_HANDLE_STMT);

    nResult = SQLFetch(handleStatement);
    if (!SQL_SUCCEEDED(nResult))
        printErr(handleStatement, SQL_HANDLE_STMT);

    std::wcout << L"Id: " << idCol << std::endl;
    std::wcout << L"Blob: " << wcharBlobCol << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

On my machine this outputs:

> Values are equal: 1
>   Length of data read is 3
>   Id: 1
>   Blob: ½═∩
>   0: 171 1: 205 2: 239
>   Id: 1
>   Blob: ABCDEF